# recursively extending and merging javascript objects

Tags: javascript, merge, extend, javascript-objects

I have written two methods for extending and merging javascript objects. It might be bad question, but I'm not sure that I'm doing it right. Can you look at code and tell if I need something to improve and if i'm doing something wrong (code works at the first glance)

```
merge: function (a, b) {
    var copy = {};
    CL.extend(copy, a, [HTMLElement, Array]);
    CL.extend(copy, b, [HTMLElement, Array]);
    return copy;
},

extend: function extend(a, b, excludeInstances) {
    for (var prop in b)
        if (b.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var isInstanceOfExcluded = false;
            if (excludeInstances)
                for (var i = 0; i < excludeInstances.length; i++)
                    if (b[prop] instanceof excludeInstances[i])
                        isInstanceOfExcluded = true;

            if (typeof b[prop] === 'object' && !isInstanceOfExcluded) {
                a[prop] = a[prop] !== undefined ? a[prop] : {};
                extend(a[prop], b[prop], excludeInstances);
            } else
                a[prop] = b[prop];
        }
}
```

Comment: Looks good so far. When in doubt, write a test suite (Jasmine, Mocha or something else) and come up with a few test cases for your usage scenarios.

Comment: Thanks @ma_il, i did not know about that testing tools. I'll try them